# How could tripple tap magnify block receiving double tap events?

Tags: android, gesture

My android app uses a custom view in which I use a GestureDetector with a setOnDoubleTapListener(..) to detect double taps. This has worked OK for years. However, recently a few customers have reported that this (double tap detection) no longer works after they had applied an android OS update. This seems related to the tripple tap magnify feature: it could be this blocks/eats the double tap in my view so that never receives the double tap via the gesture recognizer.
One specific case was reported with a Samsung Galaxy 4 phone. Disabling the OS tripple tap magnify function made my app double tap work OK again. I cannot reproduce this on A Samsung Note8, Nexus 7, and several other devices. Any idea what could be causing this & how to work around this? The actual source code is quite complicated and too complex/spread around to post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this on any devices other than the SGS4? What OS version? It may be specific to Samsung's implementation of triple-tap, or it may have been a platform bug on a specific version.

Comment: I don't know. I only know the device type in this specific case. I have also had customers report that after a system update the problem was gone. So yes, it seems an OS bug, but I'd still like to get a workaround.

Comment: Further investigation shows that this also occurs on a Nexus 7 device when the magnifier is enabled. Running the app in the debugger shows that when double tapping, onTouchEvent is called twice, but the gesturedetector never fires the onDoubleTap method. Actually it does fire it but only when the taps are in approximately equal to the double click interval limit (not faster) IOW: it is very, very hard to invoke double click: slower double clicking would result in two singleTapConfirmed-s. Seems a timing thing?